# Selenium Java~ Not deleting cookies as expected

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium

I am trying to automate testing for a webapp using the Selenium Java/Firefox Eclipse plugin.
I am trying to make a payment and then delete the cookies, to remove all the stored information. For some reason this doesnt not work.

```
public void validationCards(BufferedWriter out){
    outFile = out;
    ArrayList<String> methodList = new ArrayList<String>();
    methodList.add("validationVisaFrench");
    methodList.add("validationMCFrench");
    methodList.add("validationDiscoverFrench");
    methodList.add("validationDinerClubFrench");
    methodList.add("validationJCBFrench");
    Method method = null;

    for(String testToRun:methodList){
        try{
            method = this.getClass().getMethod(testToRun);
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
            System.out.println("This failed horribly");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            PPSCTests tempObj = this;
            this.testDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            method.invoke(tempObj);
            this.testDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cant invoke method for shits and giggles");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of one of the tests I am trying to run:

```
public void validationMCFrench(){
    System.out.println("MC French Stored Card");
    this.testDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    payment("5555555555554444", "frenchQuery");

    testSelenium.waitForPageToLoad("20000");
    String source = Jsoup.parse(testDriver.getPageSource()).text();
    System.out.println("validationMCFrench: "+source);
    successOrFail(source, "validationMCFrench", "Example");

    this.testDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
```

But it doesnt seem like any cookies are actually deleted. I am kinda stuck. Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: Huh. The [`deleteAllCookies()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#deleteAllCookies%28%29) method delete only the cookies for the current domain. Are you sure there are no cookies from other domains? These secure things tend to have their own MasterCard/Visa cookies attached to "their" sites even though you run it locally. Is there any interaction with their sites? That said, you could restart your Firefox every time and make a new profile. It's slow, but it would definitely help if there'll be no solution.

Comment: ...after you `deleteAllCookies()`, what does [`getCookies()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#getCookies%28%29) return?

Comment: Umh, the web-based cookie only holds a token that should get deleted if the cookie is removed. But that wasn't happening. I tried the getCookies(), the number of cookies decreased but nothing changed.

Comment: I made it work by "cheating". Posting the answer I went with right now.

Answer (score 0):

So the deleteAllCookies() thing didnt work. Neither did deleteAllVisibleCookies(). I went with creating a new instance of the WebDriver for the payment method.

```
public void payment(String ccNumber, String queryType){
    WebDriver driverTest = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    this.testDriver = driverTest; //then assigning it to the local WebDriver
    if(queryType.equals("query"))
        testDriver.get(testUrl + query());
    else if(queryType.equals("queryClean"))
        testDriver.get(testUrl + queryClean());
    else {
        System.out.println(testUrl + frenchQuery());
        testDriver.get(testUrl + frenchQuery());
    }
    testSelenium.waitForPageToLoad("7000");
    WebElement ccElement1 = null;
    WebElement ccExpiryElement = null;

    ccElement1 = testDriver.findElement(By.id("ccNumber"));
    ccExpiryElement = testDriver.findElement(By.id("ccExpiryDate"));

    WebElement cvv2Element1 = testDriver.findElement(By.name("ccCvv2"));
    ccElement1.sendKeys(ccNumber);
    ccExpiryElement.sendKeys("1112");//MMYY
    cvv2Element1.sendKeys("1111");
    WebElement submit = testDriver.findElement(By.id("oneTouchSubmit"));
    submit.submit();
    testSelenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
    //driverTest.close();
}
```

Its not an elegant solution but it works for what I needed to do. Creating a new instance basically works the same as deleting the cookies.